# FFMpeg attach two mp3 file to eachother, length and metadata not correct

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

Is there any way to attach two `mp3` or `ogg` or `mp4` files to eachother using ffmpeg?

I mean for example i have 2 `mp3` files, the output i need is to listen the first one and after it finished, second file plays.

so duration for output would be the duration for first + second file.

I've tried this code but the output is not correct

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

the metadata is not new for this output file and plays just first file!